# How to display the buttons based on the boolean condition?

Tags: javascript

I am new to Javascript.

I have 2 buttons `on` and `off`.

Have to set the variable `flag` to `1` when it is `on` and set the variable to `0` when it is `off`.

If flag==1, `on` button should be displayed; when flag==0, `Off` button should be displayed.

**HTML:**

```html
<button class="on">ON</button>
<button class="off">OFF</button>
```

I tried the below code, *but it did not work*.

**JS:**

```js
var flag = 0;

if (flag == 0) {
  $('.on').hide();
} else {
  $('.off').hide();
}
```

Could anyone please help?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure you want to do this and not just have the same button toggle between displaying "on" and "off"?

Comment: @Jamiec : I need separate buttons not a single button.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var flag = false;
$(function() {
  $('.on').click(e => {
    $('.on').hide();
    $('.off').show();
    flag = true;
    console.log({
      flag
    });
  });
  $('.off').click(e => {
    flag = false;
    $('.off').hide();
    $('.on').show();
    console.log({
      flag
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="on">ON </button>
<button class="off">OFF </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make this as simple as having a function to configure both buttons which also takes a callback to be called every time the state changes.

Something like:

```js
function configureToggle(onButton, offButton, initialState, onChange){
  if(initialState == 0) 
    offButton.hide();
  else onButton.hide();
  
  onButton.click(() => {
      onButton.hide();
      offButton.show();
      onChange(1);
  })
  
  offButton.click(() => {
      onButton.show();
      offButton.hide();
      onChange(0);
  })
}

configureToggle($(".on"),$(".off"), 0, value => {
    console.log("Current state is ",value);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="on" > ON </button>
<button class="off"> OFF </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

here is a solution for that

```js
$('button').on('click',function(){
   $('button').toggleClass('hide')
});
```

```css
.hide{
  display: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<button id="on"> on </button>
<button id="off" class="hide" > off </button>
```